# Meteor initial load time on *.meteor.com slow

Tags: meteor

I've read about fastrender, but does this apply to the hello world example that gets created after running `meteor create`? I've deployed a blank app to *.meteor.com and the initial load time is 2-3 seconds if I haven't cached anything.

Comment: Meteor.com isnt for production deployment, but just for testing or I would rather use for fun. If your app wont be getting any traffic for some time it may even go offline to save resources. Do not expect high speed and scalability

Comment: Try adding the fastrender package